# Fan Motor stopped working, but motor is fine. Low voltage measured

Tags: receptacle, voltage

Had to replace a broan ceiling fan, roughly 6 months ago. The new fan sounded odd, but I didn't want to buy another fan, figured I would wait until it failed again. After 6 months, it failed again. Put in a new fan, and it didn't work, either. Checked the fan on another outlet, and it turned right on, no sound, etc. Checked the voltage across the terminals of the fan switch when switched off, and it reads 69V. The voltage across the light switch in the off position (which is wired to the same hot and neutral) reads 120V, and the lights operate normally, no flickering, etc. When the light switch is on, the voltage from hot to neutral on the light switch drops to the same 69V.

The wiring seems standard. Hot from source wirenuts to two hots which are tied to the respective switches. The two switches then tie another wire that runs through the wall to the respective loads. The loads have neutral which come back and are tied to the source neutral with a wirenut.

Comment: When you say "ceiling fan", you're referring to a bath exhaust fan, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry, just a small exhaust fan in the ceiling.

Comment: Light switches don't have neutral.  The voltage across the fan switch terminals (when off) isn't right, assuming the fan was installed at the time. Get a $2 extension cord,  discard the plug, , and tie the cord's hot/neutral to the fan hot/neutral up in the ceiling.  Plug any load into the extension cord and see if the fan switch will control it. Do any wiring with breaker off, always.